# Razer Synapse unable to log in - error 3808

Tags: razer-synapse

I've got a bunch of Razer hardware that relies on Razer Synapse to run properly. My Razer Mamba is stuck at a lower resolution without it, which is unacceptable.

When I try to log in with a valid set of credentials, I get error 3801.

How do I get everything to work? My guess would be their servers are having issues somehow, but there's not much help on the matter.Can I just set Synapse to some sort of offline mode?

Comment: AWS had a rather large S3 outage in the East region today. When I left work they were still having issues. They had 30 issues when I left work and are now down to 23 open issues. So assuming Razer has most of their stuff in the East region, that could be the problem.

Comment: That's my [guess too](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35748749#35748749). That said, having an offline mode is handy, and having it here seems preferable to finding it in Reddit, especially if I need to do it again. All the eggs, one basket.

Comment: Agreed. Good find for the offline mode. The issues just went down to 22. I'll log into our AWS console later and if it's at zero, I'll post another message so you can try again with online mode.

Comment: I'm actually inclined to leave this machine in offline mode unless there's a synapse update. I can keep an eye on it through my laptop, since it also relies on synapse for keyboard backlights anyway.

Comment: [Razer says its back up](https://twitter.com/RazerSupport/status/836735588606738433)

Comment: Awesome. I was keeping an eye on it and they're down to 8 open issues. most of which are monitoring and scaling services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be happening a lot, and [this reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/razer/comments/5wpujv/system_error_3803/) thread helped me work around the issue. I do presumably lose out on sync, and its a *terrible* UI decision to hide this option IMO.

You need to open `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Razer\Synapse\Accounts\RazerLoginData.xml` and change the line that reads `<Mode>Online</Mode>` to `<Mode>Offline</Mode>`. The O must be capital - else synapse seems to crash for me.

This seems to put it in an entirely usable offline mode, though the status icon is an angry red rather than green. But that still means I can use my mouse when Razer's servers are down.

I'd seriously consider leaving this on permanently, since I don't routinely move around peripherals between systems

Answer (score 0):

Another option to use the Synapse App and thus the hardware in an **offline** usecase (i.e. on a PC without internet access, or with corporate proxy filters or with failing login problems) is to export a "Tournament Driver". You need to have a "working" PC to set up your settings and profiles and then you're able to export them all into an installable File.

The option can be found in the "menu" up right in the application:

[image]

This helped me several times to use the mouse correctly on really old, internet-inaccessible, or corporate Laptops. Nonetheless - the practice of requiring internet access to use basic hardware functionality (wheel tilts for example) is an absolute antipattern and we as tech savy people should try to steer companies away from making this a regular practice. I'll rethink ever buying a razer mouse again :(